# increment all elements from a vector

Tags: java, vector

let's say I have this vector

```
[20, 17, 29, 0]
```

and I want it to become

```
[21, 18, 30, 1]
```

as you can see all the elements were simply upped by one. how do I do this without it looking like lousy code

Answer (score 3):

The simplest approach is probably just

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
  list.set(i, list.get(i) + 1);
}
```

...though in Java 8 you could just do

```
list.replaceAll(i -> i + 1);
```

Comment: +1 for the Java 8 solution I was just about to post.

Comment: it added 3ms to my execution time!

Comment: ...and?  I'm not sure what you were hoping for, or if that's good or bad for whatever reason.

Comment: @user3453281 One thing you might want to consider is if you are processing the data after this then increment it there. Other than that there is no other way (what else could a computer do? It has to increment each memory element individually.)